# passing post array to function

Tags: php

How can i pass a post array to a functing then pull out the params i.e

so i am posting the following.

```
url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ftest&userId=680410999&location=Cardiff&lang=en_US&social=facebook
```

can i grab it like this from the function????

```
function login($_POST){

//then output the var her.

$_POST['url']; etc

}
```

this is to save me doing the following in my ajax.php file

```
function login($_POST['url'],$_POST['userId'],$_POST['location'],$_POST['lang']){



    }
```

any help pls

Comment: Concretise what isn't working with example two pls?

Comment: I think you should learn about [functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) in PHP first

Answer (score 4):

First you should use `$_GET` and not `$_POST`. Second you don't need to call your function parameter as `$_GET`. You can do this:

```
function login($array)
{
   // do stuff with array
}
```

and then call the function in this way:

```
login($_GET);
```

An additional suggest is to read the following quote and that is the difference of **actual parameters** towards **formal parameters**:

> Formal parameters are the parameters as they are known in the function
>   definition. Actual parameters (also known as arguments) are what are
>   passed by the caller.

Answer (score 0):

If I unserstand you correctly you want a function that you call and pass it an array (in your case the `$_POST` or `$_GET` array) as a parameter.

So your function would look something like this:

```
// not sure what you're doing with your login options but here's an example of getting them out of the array and putting them in variables - using the url as an example here...
var url;

function login($loginOptions) {

    // set the url from the array
    url = $loginOptions["url"];

    // do the same for all your other variable...
}
```

Then you would call your function like so:

```
login($_POST); // or $_login($_GET); depending on what you're using
```

And that's it!

Answer (score 0):

The other answers you have got should solve this problem for you.

Just some more advice, remember to clean any `$_POST` and `$_GET` data that you are using in your code.

For example, if you are using it in a database query then you will need to use `mysql_real_escape_string();` and if you are echo'ing the data then use `htmlentities();`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is parsing array to a function for this I will tell you to use a function and connected it with SESSION as this below. You can use the $_GET[$var] to retrieve the variable but it's quite hard to be handled by the method get, you can use the method $_POST and combine it with session to save the data , I will explain how to collaborate the session each page so that you can easily retrieve the variable you wanted. 
Here's the code :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset ($_POST['postedit']))
    {
         $_SESSION['url'] = $_POST['urlsend'];
         header("location:dua.php");
    }
?>
<html>
    <body>
      <form action="satu.php" method="POST">
            Name : <input type="text" name="urlsend"> <br> <br>
            <input type="submit" name="postedit" value="SEND DATA">
      </form>  
    </body>
</html>

<?php
session_start();
if(isset ($_SESSION['url']))
{
    //if data empty then will be redirected to the previous page
   echo $_SESSION['url'];
}
?>
```

I created with dynamic data even you can choose to use this method or other method. I hope you can understand.